# Setting up Mac Terminal w/ Node

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I am trying to setup my Mac terminal for my coding class, and hit a wall when setting up the Node part. Below is the error message I receive  on my terminal. Any suggestions on how to correct it?

```
mkdir: /usr/local/opt/nvm/alias/lts: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/opt/nvm/alias/lts: Permission denied
nvm_list_aliases:12: no matches found: /usr/local/opt/nvm/alias/*
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
nvm_list_aliases:36: no matches found: /usr/local/opt/nvm/alias/lts/*
```

Comment: What is the command you're running?

Comment: What process are you following to install, if you are open to suggestions, I would highly advice using homebrew https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Homebrew to avoid getting into "sudo" permissions issues. Homebrew is a commonly used package manager for macOS.

Open an terminal and run the following command to install:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It might ask you to install developer tools for MacOs that's completely ok. Once finished check the version with:

```
$ brew -v
```

Now, install Node via Homebrew:

```
$ brew install node
```

Finally check the Node and NPM versions

```
$node -v
$npm -v
```

More info at:
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score 0):

Install with brew, and follow the post install instructions.